# Custom xtics in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Trying to do a function plot in gnuplot. How can one add custom xtics to it? The x-axis tics starts from "0 6 12 18 24" based on the function plotted. I want them to be "6 12 18 24 6". Is it possible?

Comment: "6 12 18 24 6" are weird tics, are you sure the last 6 is what you want? Do you only want to change the tics or do you also want to change the range of the plot itself?

Comment: 1) The x-axis actually represents hours, so I want them to appear as 6am to 6am in a 24hour cycle.
2) I just want to change the tics not the range of plot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes:

```
set xtics ("6" 0, "12" 6, "18" 12, "24" 18, "6" 24)
```